# Background subtraction for a signal and error analysis

Tags: error-analysis, covariance

I use a CCD to see the split of a energy level due to Zeeman effect.

I have a 1 dimensional CCD of 7926 pixel of 7μm each one. My CCD analyze a region 2 dimensional, and then it steps forward 200 times. So, I have a matrix like this:

[image: "matrix"].

I select the background between 40 and 60 pixel and I calculate for each row the mean value. Then, i project these 7926 mean values over the Y axis. So, for each bins of the row of the matrix (i.e. 3040), I subtract the value of the content of 3040 pixel of the background

This is my background:

[image: "background"]

(in x there are the pixels of my CCD and y is the intensity).

I have to subtract the background from the signal, subtracting bin for bin.
At each bins of the background it is associated an error $\sigma = \sqrt{N}$ where $N$ is the bin content.

Each bins of the signal has an error $\sqrt{N}$, but when i subtract the background how can I calculate the exact error of the pure signal?

If $Z'_i$ is the bin content after the subtraction, $Z_i$ the bin content before and $Y_i$ the bin content of the background, then $Z'_i = Z_i - Y_i$ and the error (throw the propagation) $\sigma_{Y_i} = \sqrt{\sigma_{Z'_i}^2 + \sigma_{Y_i}^2 + \cdots}$

In fact, I think, there should be a term of covariance. How can I compute it?